# MSXML ServerXMLHTTP- Calling web service

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, msxml, msxml6

Problem: I am getting the following error output from `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` check;

```
Err.Number :-1072954818  
Err.Source :msxml6.dll  
Err.Source :This method cannot be called until the open method has been called.
```

Code:

```
dim objHttpRequest
dim gw_menu_request
dim HTTPMethod

HTTPMethod="POST"
Set objHttpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")    
gw_menu_request = "http://test.com?q=headerexpose/expose_headers/expose_json"       
objHttpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
objHttpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", 0
objHttpRequest.open HTTPMethod, gw_menu_request, false          
Response.write(objHttpRequest.ResponseXML)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
  Response.Write "Err.Number :" & Err.Number  & "<br/>"
  Response.Write "Err.Source :" & Err.Source & "<br/>"
  Response.Write "Err.Source :" & Err.Description  & "<br/>"
  Response.Write "Err.File :" & Err.File & "<br/>"
End If
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You want `Response.write(objHttpRequest.ResponseXML.xml)`

Comment: No, That too dont work, I even try with ResponseText. nothing is working

Comment: Too quick that was one issue the main one is the order you are calling `Open()`, I've posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37186423/692942) that explains it further.

Comment: How did you get on did [our discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111753/discussion-between-ramakrishnan-and-lankymart) help?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is exactly as the described in the error, you are trying to set Request Headers without first calling `Open()`. You are also missing the `Send()` method to send the request before a response can be received.

```vb
Dim objHttpRequest
Dim gw_menu_request
Dim HTTPMethod

HTTPMethod="POST"
Set objHttpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")    
gw_menu_request = "http://test.com?q=headerexpose/expose_headers/expose_json"
'Open request specifying method and URL to call
objHttpRequest.open HTTPMethod, gw_menu_request, False
'Set any HTTP headers needed before sending.      
objHttpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
objHttpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", 0
'Send the request
objHttpRequest.Send 
Response.write(objHttpRequest.ResponseXML.Xml)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
  Response.Write "Err.Number :" & Err.Number  & "<br/>"
  Response.Write "Err.Source :" & Err.Source & "<br/>"
  Response.Write "Err.Source :" & Err.Description  & "<br/>"
  Response.Write "Err.File :" & Err.File & "<br/>"
End If
```

You also want `ResponseXML.Xml` or you will receive a

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch

because you are trying to output the object not the `Xml` property that contains the XML string representation.

Comment: @Ramakrishnan Sorry realised I missed out the `Send()` which will also cause the problem due to the `Response` not being available until the `Request` is sent.

Comment: I am getting the same error - "This method cannot be called until the open method has been called"

Comment: lankymart- How to fix that problem, any clues.

Comment: @Ramakrishnan Have you looked at my most recent edit in regards to not setting `Send()`?, it's hard to workout which comment you have seen and replied to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111753/discussion-between-ramakrishnan-and-lankymart).